# Why does ostream::operator<< allow ostringstream arg?

Tags: c++, std, ostream

This produces garbage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
main()
{
    std::ostringstream s1;
    s1 << "s" << 1;
    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
}
```

This produces garbage.  I realize the fix is to use `s1.str()`.  I'm wondering why `ostream::operator<<` can take the `ostringstream` arg if it "doesn't work properly".

Comment: this [doesn't compile for me on either gcc or clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d213d94b7b5638a2). What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: Doesn't compile with [Visual Studio 2015 either](http://rextester.com/WZPW65979)

Comment: @jaggedSpire Probably a pre-C++11 one.

Comment: @SebastianRedl [looks like you're right](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63d66f63a98d11cf)

Comment: Where is your return type for `main`?

Comment: @jaggedSpire g++ (GCC) 4.8.3, with -std=c++11 -- and I gather (per the 'duplicate' answer) that this is a known issue in g++.

Comment: @JohnH. well the explanation dupe-linked is the probable one. It seems any version of gcc after 5.0 changes the behavior to the expected compiler error, though. You might want to upgrade your compiler if you can--gcc head is presently at 7.0, and 6.1's pretty common.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Corporate is moving to 5.2 Any Day Now...  Thanks much for all you's help.